# What is this 2x1 decorated brick with green screen?

Tags: part-identification

This is not a slope part, just a plain white 2x1 brick with decoration.

[image: 2x1 brick with decoration]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's [Brick 1 x 2 with TV Screen and 3 Buttons Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3004px4)

Comment: It was part of a (BrickLink-labelled) minifig?! <https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=alp007>

Comment: @RSchulz that was [just one of its uses](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3004px4&in=S)